# Chrome multiple print jobs with callbacks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, callback

first question on my part. Hope to be precise.
I have the following scenario:

I render a page displaying data to be printed. The user has two options represented by buttons: Print 1 and Print 2 (they are named differently, but that does not matter). I will only explain 1 kind of print because the other one works basically the same, just shows some extra columns via classes and a separate print stylesheet).

So when the user clicks on a print button, the following shall happen:

1. A JavaScript function will be called checking via JQuery AJAX if the conditions for printing are met. This works fine, the success function is called, data are loaded etc.
2. Depending on the conditions being met, one of two callback functions to the function shall be executed. If conditions are not met, only an alert is displayed, but if they are, the callback function shall initiate two print jobs (One in landscape, one portrait. I have already read that there is no browser-compliant way to force the layout there :/, so there is no other choice than asking the user to make the appropriate settings).

Now, here comes my problem: Only the *last* of the two print jobs is executed. The first one is not processed. I suspect Chrome somehow overrides them or something. But whatever I do, as soon as the second print job comes to action via window.print(), only that one happens. The weird thing is, that I got it working when it did not implement it via callbacks. This is some pseudo code that is happening:

```
function checkConditions(yesCallback, noCallback) {
    $.ajax({url, data, success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if (conditionsMet) {
            yesCallback();
        } else {
            noCallback();
        }  
    }});    
}
```

Here the code when the button is clicked:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    checkConditions(
        function() {
            alert('Print this in landscape mode');
            window.print();
            $.ajax({success: function(data, textStatus) {
                //append new data, arrange them etc. 
            }});
            //and print again
            alert('Now print in portrait mode, please');
            window.print();
        }, 
        function() {
            alert('Cannot print. Conditions not met.');
        });
};
```

The callbacks work fine, they are called and processed, both print statements are passed. 
But basically what happens is: firstAlert -> secondAlert -> print().
Very frustrating. Even more frustrating is that it works in IE (even though it opens 2 dialogs which can be confusing).

Does anyone know how to work around that in Chrome? Or how to fix it properly? Printing is a field that I have very little experience with and I am annoyed that there is no possibility to compliantly change layout, as it is a report application where the print layout should be forced.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution that works at least, though not nice: Opening a new window, writing the content to that and printing it from there. However, this produces additional overhead, as the page has to load the stylesheets, which I wanted to avoid. I am still open to a better solution :).